# access cell array by two vector not pairwise

Tags: matlab, cell-array

If I have a Cell array 2*2 where A{i,j} is a matrix, and I have two vectors v=1:2,c=1:2.

I want A(v,c) to return only A{1,1} and A{2,2} but matlab returns every combination of the two(aka also returns A{1,2} and A{2,1}).

Is there a way without using loops or cellfun ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suspect you are doing is something like this:

```
B = A(v, c);
```

When you specify vectors to index into `A`, it finds the **intersection** of coordinates and gives you those elements.  As such, with your indexing you are basically returning all of the elements in `A`.

If you want just the top left and lower right elements, use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) instead.   You can grab the column-major indices of those locations in your cell array, then slice into your cell array with these indices:

```
ind = sub2ind(size(A), v, c);
B = A(ind);
```

## Example

Let's create a sample 2 x 2 cell array:

```
A = cell(2,2);
A{1,1} = ones(2);
A{1,2} = 2*ones(2);
A{2,1} = 3*ones(2);
A{2,2} = 4*ones(2);
```

Row 1, column 1 is a 2 x 2 matrix of all 1s.  Row 1, column 2 is a 2 x 2 matrix of 2s, row 2 column 1 is a 2 x 2 matrix of all 3s and the last entry is a 2 x 2 matrix of all 4s.

With `v = 1:2; c=1:2;`, running the above code gives us:

```
>> celldisp(B)

B{1} =

     1     1
     1     1

B{2} =

     4     4
     4     4
```

As you can see, we picked out the top left and bottom right entries exactly.

## Minor Note

If it's seriously just a cell array of 2 x 2, and you only want to pick out the top left and lower right elements, you can just do:

```
B = A([1 4]);
```

`sub2ind` would equivalently return 1 and 4 as the column major indices for the top left and lower right elements.  This avoids the `sub2ind` call and still achieves what you want.